# c# draw an arc in a rectangle

Tags: c#, graphics, geometry

Spiral:

[image]

I have coded squares in C# based on the Fibonacci series exactly as shown in the included image. The problem I am having is trying to draw the arcs. I am not sure if I should be using arcs, curves or bezier curves. I assume an arc is what I want, but I have been unable to get the results I am trying for.

If someone could show me an example of how to draw an arc from corner to corner within a square it would be very much appreciated. I just hard coded the squares for fun. I want to try to write an algorithm to generate them, but right now I am stumped by the behavior of the arcs.

Comment: any code to share ? so we see what are you doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(50, 50);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.DrawArc(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), 0, 90);
}
```

### Parameters

- Stroke color
- Bounding box for the circle the arc would be part of
- Starting angle (in degrees)
- Ending angle (in degrees)

The arc is drawn clockwise from the starting arc. To do a counterclockwise arc, supply a negative value for the ending angle.

Comment: Thank you, I think the starting and ending angle is my problem, it is a bit late now, but I will try this first thing tomorrow.

Comment: I got it to work, your solution got me close, but I realized in order for the arc to reach each corner, the bounding box must be twice the size of the actual square. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Protium Yes, I worded that part badly. The bounding box is the size of the entire circle that the arc would draw if you drew a full circle. (i.e. 0-360 degrees)

Comment: [![finished.jpg](https://s28.postimg.org/m0132pf8t/finished.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/sdq65yk4p/) I got it, although I had to do some strange offsetting of some of the bounding rectangles, I will have to play with this some more :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(50, 50);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.DrawArc(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), 0, 90);
}
```

It seems the bounding box must be twice the size of the square in order for the arc to go from corner to corner.

[Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtLIY.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wasn't getting the behavior I wanted for several reasons. Thanks again for your time.